# Android Dropbox, file created but not uploaded

Tags: java, android, dropbox, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

recently i try to play around with Dropbox android application integration

this application obtain user current location and automatically upload it to dropbox

The problem is that, i failed to upload the file. 
Toast shows "there seems to be an error"

here's the main activity

```
  @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("Location_Filename", Location_Filename);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AndroidAuthSession session = mApi.getSession();

    // The next part must be inserted in the onResume() method of the
    // activity from which session.startAuthentication() was called, so
    // that Dropbox authentication completes properly.
    if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
        try {
            // Mandatory call to complete the auth
            session.finishAuthentication();

            // Store it locally in our app for later use
            storeAuth(session);
            setLoggedIn(true);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            showToast("Couldn't authenticate with Dropbox:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            Log.i(TAG, "Error authenticating", e);
        }
    }
}

// This is what gets called on finishing a media piece to import
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == NEW_LOCATION) {
        // return from file upload
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = null;
            if (data != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
            }
            if (uri == null && Location_Filename != null) {
                uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Location_Filename));
            }
            File file = new File(Location_Filename);

            if (uri != null) {
                UploadLocation upload = new UploadLocation(this, mApi, LOCATION_DIR, file);
                upload.execute();
            }
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unknown Activity Result from locationImport: "
                    + resultCode);
        }
        }
    }





/**
 * Convenience function to change UI state based on being logged in
 */
private void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
    mLoggedIn = loggedIn;
    if (loggedIn) {

        mDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {

        mDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}

private void checkAppKeySetup() {
    // Check to make sure that we have a valid app key
    if (APP_KEY.startsWith("CHANGE") ||
            APP_SECRET.startsWith("CHANGE")) {
        showToast("You must apply for an app key and secret from developers.dropbox.com, and add them to the DBRoulette ap before trying it.");
        finish();
        return;
    }

    // Check if the app has set up its manifest properly.
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String scheme = "db-" + APP_KEY;
    String uri = scheme + "://" + AuthActivity.AUTH_VERSION + "/test";
    testIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    if (0 == pm.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, 0).size()) {
        showToast("URL scheme in your app's " +
                "manifest is not set up correctly. You should have a " +
                "com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity with the " +
                "scheme: " + scheme);
        finish();
    }
}

private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast error = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    error.show();
}

/**
 * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
 * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
 * time (which is not to be done, ever).
 */
private void loadAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
    String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
    if (key == null || secret == null || key.length() == 0 || secret.length() == 0) return;

    if (key.equals("oauth2:")) {
        // If the key is set to "oauth2:", then we can assume the token is for OAuth 2.
        session.setOAuth2AccessToken(secret);
    } else {
        // Still support using old OAuth 1 tokens.
        session.setAccessTokenPair(new AccessTokenPair(key, secret));
    }
}

/**
 * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a local
 * store, rather than storing user name & password, and re-authenticating each
 * time (which is not to be done, ever).
 */
private void storeAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
    // Store the OAuth 2 access token, if there is one.
    String oauth2AccessToken = session.getOAuth2AccessToken();
    if (oauth2AccessToken != null) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, "oauth2:");
        edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, oauth2AccessToken);
        edit.commit();
        return;
    }
    // Store the OAuth 1 access token, if there is one.  This is only necessary if
    // you're still using OAuth 1.
    AccessTokenPair oauth1AccessToken = session.getAccessTokenPair();
    if (oauth1AccessToken != null) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, oauth1AccessToken.key);
        edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, oauth1AccessToken.secret);
        edit.commit();
        return;
    }
}

private void clearKeys() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.clear();
    edit.commit();
}

private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
    AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

    AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair);
    loadAuth(session);
    return session;
}
```

}

here is the Upload location class

```
public class UploadLocation extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {

    private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
    private String mPath;
    private File mFile;

    private long mFileLen;
    private UploadRequest mRequest;
    private Context mContext;
    private final ProgressDialog mDialog;

    private String mErrorMsg;


    public UploadLocation(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath,
                          File file) {
        // We set the context this way so we don't accidentally leak activities
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        mFileLen = file.length();
        mApi = api;
        mPath = dropboxPath;
        mFile = file;

        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mDialog.setMax(100);
        mDialog.setMessage("Uploading " + file.getName());
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setProgress(0);
        mDialog.setButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // This will cancel the putFile operation
                mRequest.abort();
            }
        });
        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // By creating a request, we get a handle to the putFile operation,
            // so we can cancel it later if we want to
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
            String path = mPath + mFile.getName();
            mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(),
                    new ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public long progressInterval() {
                    // Update the progress bar every half-second or so
                    return 500;
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                    publishProgress(bytes);
                }
            });

            if (mRequest != null) {
                mRequest.upload();
                return true;
            }

        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            // This session wasn't authenticated properly or user unlinked
            mErrorMsg = "This app wasn't authenticated properly.";
        } catch (DropboxFileSizeException e) {
            // File size too big to upload via the API
            mErrorMsg = "This file is too big to upload";
        } catch (DropboxPartialFileException e) {
            // We canceled the operation
            mErrorMsg = "Upload canceled";
        } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
            // Server-side exception.  These are examples of what could happen,
            // but we don't do anything special with them here.
            if (e.error == DropboxServerException._401_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                // Unauthorized, so we should unlink them.  You may want to
                // automatically log the user out in this case.
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._403_FORBIDDEN) {
                // Not allowed to access this
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._404_NOT_FOUND) {
                // path not found (or if it was the thumbnail, can't be
                // thumbnailed)
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE) {
                // user is over quota
            } else {
                // Something else
            }
            // This gets the Dropbox error, translated into the user's language
            mErrorMsg = e.body.userError;
            if (mErrorMsg == null) {
                mErrorMsg = e.body.error;
            }
        } catch (DropboxIOException e) {
            // Happens all the time, probably want to retry automatically.
            mErrorMsg = "Network error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxParseException e) {
            // Probably due to Dropbox server restarting, should retry
            mErrorMsg = "Dropbox error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            // Unknown error
            mErrorMsg = "Unknown error.  Try again.";
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
        int percent = (int)(100.0*(double)progress[0]/mFileLen + 0.5);
        mDialog.setProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            showToast("Image successfully uploaded");
        } else {
            showToast(mErrorMsg);
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }
}
```

Logcat

```js
04-09 00:03:47.053: I/Main Activity(2010): Importing Location: /storage/sdcard/BEB.txt
04-09 00:03:47.053: I/ActivityManager(1230): START u0 {(has extras)} from uid 10056 on display 0
04-09 00:03:47.080: W/Main Activity(2010): Unknown Activity Result from mediaImport: 0
04-09 00:03:47.138: W/EGL_emulation(2010): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-09 00:03:47.138: W/OpenGLRenderer(2010): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa51571a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Hope someone can help, its really bothering me
Much appreciated, thank you

Comment: [logcat](https://politecuriosity.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/logcat.jpg) please.

Comment: To reiterate what maveň said, if there was an issue uploading to Dropbox, there should be some useful information or error in the log, so please check that and update your question with it if you still need help.

Comment: Is that all of the log? There doesn't seem to be anything related to Dropbox in it. Also, the code shows some errors via Toast. Is anything else appearing there?

Comment: @Greg the logcat start after the dropbox authetication process, when the app detect the user location